# Learning PDO simple form input not submitting to database

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I've started learning PDO yesterday and I thought I had it down but I've run into an error again while trying to submit a simple form. I'm using the example on w3schools but with a form input.

index.php

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder"Enter Your Name">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my page that processes the form:

submit.php

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "testuser";
    $password = "testpassword";
    $dbname = "testdb";

    $nickname = $_POST['name'];

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        //Set PDO Error Mode to Exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name)
        VALUES (:nickname)";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
?>
```

The Error I'm getting is:

> INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (:nickname)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':nickname)' at line 2

Comment: Please learn how to use prepared statements http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: W3Schools is probably not the best place. Here is one [tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html) that makes PDO easier.

Comment: *"I'm using the example on w3schools but with a form input."* - I'd like to know what the URL is.

Comment: Thanks for that, it seems there was alot missing from the w3schools example

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: *Exactly Ralph*, I wouldn't be surprised at the lack of detail @Fred-ii-

Comment: This is their link to their prepared statements method http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp not the one you gave which isn't a bad example. However, this http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements is the one you should have consulted.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Actually, their example isn't that bad *Sam* http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Hmmmm, seems they're upping their game @Fred-ii-

Comment: Yeah, they've gotten better over the years; probably all the flack they've been getting. @JayBlanchard I'm not completely against W3 Schools and TBH, they were one of the first places I started to learn when getting into PHP years ago. Remember they are a "school", and one can't learn all the ins and outs of the industry. One must keep reaching for higher goals; such as doing their own research and being savvy ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy you also can't rely on an "id" alone for `<input type="text" id="name" placeholder"Enter Your Name">` it needs a name attribute for it `<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder"Enter Your Name">` something only one person pointed out below (which I edited slightly) and not in the answer you accepted. They should have picked up on that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah I saw that, I normally do use name attributes but I forgot on this example.
I have a question that I don't think is worth opening up another thread so I'll see if I can get a simple answer.
What would be the best way to iterate through the database? The example on http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp works but I don't need the table format.

Comment: just remove the table-related code

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did but the structure is also in the foreach loop and if i take that out it just returns the word array, nothing else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use prepared statments, try something like this:

```
// query
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (name)
    VALUES (:nickname)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':nickname'=>$nickname));
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to create a prepared statement, then bind to it a value, that you want to insert. You can more read about PDO from official php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

```
    <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "testuser";
        $password = "testpassword";
        $dbname = "testdb";

        $nickname = $_POST['name'];

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            //Set PDO Error Mode to Exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name)
            VALUES (:nickname)";
            $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $stm->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
            // use exec() because no results are returned
            $stm->execute();
            echo "New record created successfully";
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $conn = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: I tried your answer and now I'm getting this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::exec()

Comment: Sorry, it's $stm->execute();

Comment: real simple solution to this @Mr.Smithyyy  consult the manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements ;-) always.

Answer (score 1):

Your form input needs a `name` attribute, as this is how it is referenced.

```
<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
```

You cannot rely on an "id" alone.

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- Having used error reporting, would have signalled an "Undefined index name..." notice.

The `name` attribute is the value that is in the PHP `$_POST` array so the above example will give:

```
$_POST['name'] = <the value you entered into the name input box>
```

To further clarify, the `id` value of the `<input>` element *does not appear in the PHP $_POST data*. The POST data ***requires*** a name attribute to submit data from the form.

Comment: you just completely destroyed what I modified and doesn't match the OP's input. `$nickname = $_POST['name'];` and not `nameX1`

Comment: Sorry @Fred-ii- , I wanted to show how the input name attribute is used in the PHP to reference the value. I don't think I *completely* destroyed your intent.

Comment: future readers to the question will notice the difference. You know, and I know, but others won't agree.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I wanted to use a different `name` value to differentiate the `name='name'` and `id='name'` so that the OP can clearly see which one sets the POST array key value, it's an example to show rather than a direct correction of his code.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
$q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (:nickname)");

// Variant #1
$q->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();

// Variant #2
$q->bindValue(':nickname', $nickname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$q->execute();

// Variant #3
$q->execute([':nickname' => $nickname]);
```

---

**Also note**:

> [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) unlike [`bindValue()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php), **bounds the variable as a reference** and it will only be evaluated at the time [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) is called.

Answer (score 0):

you're almost there, you have missed a couple of steps.  By using the :name marker in the sql string you are identifying that you will bind variables to this marker.  this means that you need to have PDO prepare the sql query statement first, then bind your variable to it, then send it to the server.

like the following example:

```
...
$name = $_POST['name']
$sql = "INSERT INTO nameTable (name) VALUES(:name)";
//this is what you missed
$stmt= $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
//the following is the way of executing a prepared statement, you keep using the $stmt variable, rather than the $con one.
$stmt->execute();
```

That should get it working.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing two steps:

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        //Set PDO Error Mode to Exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test (name)
        VALUES (:nickname)";
        $conn->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql,array(':nickname' => $username));
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
```

Comment: `exec` does not take a second argument. you would need to have the complete SQL to pass to exec, not placeholders to be bound.

Comment: can you elaborate what exactly the two steps are?

Comment: @Martin You are missing the `PDO::prepare` part and then `PDOStatement::execute` but this answer is a bit confused and incorrect in attempting to show you how to do that. Look at @vanadium23 or @dharmang answers.

Comment: thanks @prodigitalson but I was trying to encourage niyou to explain his answer rather than just post some code without any explanation or educational value to it.

Comment: Oh sorry @Martin - I got confused, through you were OP for some reason.